Individual sessions for each webview in Tauri application
When it comes to Electron, you can create partitions for each webview and they have differnet sessions.
How do I achieve in the Tauri.
I'm able to put multiple webview in a single window. But don't know how to preserve the sessions of each webview.
use tauri::{LogicalPosition, LogicalSize, WebviewUrl, Manager};
use std::fs::{File, OpenOptions};
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct WebviewData {
    label: String,
    url: String,
    cookies: String, // Store cookies as a string
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct WebviewManager {
    count: usize,
    webviews: Vec<WebviewData>,
}

const WEBVIEW_STATE_FILE: &str = "./webview_state.json";

// Helper to save webview state
fn save_webview_state(state: &WebviewManager) -> Result<(), String> {
    let state_json = serde_json::to_string(state).map_err(|err| err.to_string())?;
    let mut file = OpenOptions::new()
        .create(true)
        .write(true)
        .truncate(true)
        .open(WEBVIEW_STATE_FILE)
        .map_err(|err| err.to_string())?;
    file.write_all(state_json.as_bytes()).map_err(|err| err.to_string())?;
    Ok(())
}

// Helper to load webview state
fn load_webview_state() -> Result<WebviewManager, String> {
    let mut file = File::open(WEBVIEW_STATE_FILE).map_err(|_| "No saved state found".to_string())?;
    let mut state_json = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut state_json).map_err(|err| err.to_string())?;
    let state: WebviewManager = serde_json::from_str(&state_json).map_err(|err| err.to_string())?;
    Ok(state)
}

// Command to create a new webview with a unique name and cookies
#[tauri::command]
fn create_webview(app: tauri::AppHandle, state: tauri::State<'_, Arc<Mutex<WebviewManager>>>, url: String, cookies: String) -> Result<String, String> {
    let mut manager = state.lock().unwrap();
    manager.count += 1;
    let webview_name = format!("window{}", manager.count);

    let window = app.get_window("main").unwrap();
    let width = window.inner_size().unwrap().width as f64;
    let height = window.inner_size().unwrap().height as f64;

    window.add_child(
        tauri::webview::WebviewBuilder::new(&webview_name, WebviewUrl::External(url.clone().parse().unwrap()))
            .auto_resize(),
        LogicalPosition::new(0., 0.),
        LogicalSize::new(width / manager.count as f64, height),
    ).map_err(|err| format!("Failed to create webview: {}", err))?;

    manager.webviews.push(WebviewData { label: webview_name.clone(), url, cookies });
    save_webview_state(&manager).map_err(|err| format!("Failed to save webview state: {}", err))?;

    Ok(webview_name)
}

// Command to save cookies for a WebView
#[tauri::command]
fn save_cookies(state: tauri::State<'_, Arc<Mutex<WebviewManager>>>, label: String, cookies: String) -> Result<(), String> {
    let mut manager = state.lock().unwrap();
    if let Some(webview) = manager.webviews.iter_mut().find(|wv| wv.label == label) {
        webview.cookies = cookies;
    }
    save_webview_state(&manager).map_err(|err| format!("Failed to save cookies: {}", err))?;
    Ok(())
}
#[tauri::command]
fn greet(name: &str) -> String {
    format!("Hello, {}! You've been greeted from Rust!", name)
}

#[cfg_attr(mobile, tauri::mobile_entry_point)]
pub fn run() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .setup(|app| {
            let width = 800.;
            let height = 600.;
            let window = tauri::window::WindowBuilder::new(app, "main")
                .inner_size(width, height)
                .build()?;

            // Load saved webview state if available
            let webview_manager = match load_webview_state() {
                Ok(manager) => manager,
                Err(_) => WebviewManager { count: 0, webviews: vec![] },
            };

            // Recreate saved webviews
            for webview in &webview_manager.webviews {
                window.add_child(
                    tauri::webview::WebviewBuilder::new(&webview.label, WebviewUrl::External(webview.url.parse().unwrap()))
                        .auto_resize(),
                    LogicalPosition::new(0., 0.), // Adjust position logic as needed
                    LogicalSize::new(width / webview_manager.count as f64, height),
                )?;
            }

            Ok(())
        })
        .manage(Arc::new(Mutex::new(WebviewManager { count: 0, webviews: vec![] }))) // Initialize state manager
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![greet, create_webview, save_cookies])
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}

The above code is lib.rs in src of tauri.
It has the code to create a webview based on a call from the react application.
